# Comment is populating but not showing inside my post

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to show comments below every post. When I `console.log(foundBlog)` comment is showing in terminal but comments are not visible in the web page.

I have created 3 models: `blogPost`, `comments` and `User`.

**Comment Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

**Blog Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            re: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

**Show route of each Post**

```
router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
    Blog.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundBlog){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/");
            console.log(foundBlog);
        } else {
            res.render("blogs/show", {blog: foundBlog});
        }
    })
})
```

**Show template of each Post**

```
<%- include('../partials/header') %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" style="margin-top: 5px">
        <div>
            <h1><%=blog.title%></h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Submitted by <%= blog.author.username%></h4>
            <span><h5> on <%= blog.created.toDateString() %></h5></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src = "<%= blog.image %>" >
    <div style="word-break: break-word;"><p><%- blog.description %></p></div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div style="margin-right: 15px">
            <button class="btn btn-warning"><a href='/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/edit'>Edit Blog</a></button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action='/blogs/<%=blog._id%>?_method=DELETE' method='POST'>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="well">
    <div class="text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/new">Add a New Comment</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <strong><%= comment.author.username %></strong>
                <span  class="float-right">10 days ago </span>
                <p>
                     <%= comment.text %>     
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }) %>
</div>
<%- include('../partials/footer') %>
```

App.js

```
var express               = require("express"),
    bodyParser            = require("body-parser"),
    app                   = express(),
    mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
    bcrypt                = require('bcrypt'),
    flash                 = require('connect-flash'),
    methodOverride        = require('method-override'),
    expressSanitizer      = require('express-sanitizer'),
    User                  = require('./models/user'),
    Blog                  = require('./models/blog'),
    Comment               = require('./models/comment'),
    passport              = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy         = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var commentRoutes = require("./routes/comments"),
    blogRoutes = require("./routes/blogs"),
    indexRoutes       = require("./routes/index");    

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/post',  {useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: "what the duck",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()))
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Add comment template

```
<%- include('../partials/header') %>

<div class="container">
<h1 style="text-align: center">Add a new Comment to <%= blog.title %></h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[text]" placeholder="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">Go Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%- include('../partials/footer') %>
```

Comment: So you see the document populated correctly when you print to the console?

Comment: yes. Comment text along with author name is visible in console.

Comment: do you get any error in the browsers console?

Comment: No. I do not get any error in browser console.

Comment: You are getting an error when ferchin the Blog post, the if statement is executing,  could you console.log that error?